# Error while Installing Math::Pari

Tags: perl, module, cpan, cpanm

I'm trying to install Math::Pari module but getting error.

I'm installing on Windows Server 2012R2, I've Strawberry perl v5.18.4.1 32-bit currently installed on it.

Actually Math::Pari is dependency for Net::SSH::W32Perl and I want to install that module.

Following is the error log. Please Give me step by step installation procedure.

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7039 on perl 5.018004 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\script/.cpanm/work/1438929213.2276
You have make C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.08
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.02
Searching Math::Pari () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Math::Pari
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.010808.zip
-> OK
Unpacking Math-Pari-2.010808.zip
Entering Math-Pari-2.010808/
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (6.98)
Configuring Math-Pari-2.010808
Running Makefile.PL
Did not find GP/PARI build directory around.

Apparently, you are running a 64-bit Perl built with MicroSoft's compilers.
GP/PARI (at least the versions I know how to work with, 2.1.* and 2.3.*)
cannot be built in this environment.  I won't auto-download GP/PARI.

If you believe that this message is printed erroneously, please report
(see files README and INSTALL), and put force_download on the command line:
   perl Makefile.PL force_download

One can rerun Makefile.PL after fetching GP/PARI archive (e.g., pari-2.1.7.tgz,
or pari-2.3.4.tar.gz) manually to the current directory, or a (grand)parent
directory of the current directory.

  [Keep in mind that the numbers "inside version" of Math::Pari module
   correspond to the last versions of GP/PARI it was tested with (additionally,
   2.0108* works best with the last 2.1.* version, 2.1.7).

   As an alternative to having archive in CWD or its (grand)parent, specify
       pari_tgz=PATH_TO_TAR_GZ
   option to Makefile.PL.

   There is no need to extract the archive, or build GP/PARI; but if you
   have it extracted [and patched, if needed], you may specify
       paridir=PATH_TO_DIST_DIR
   option to Makefile.PL instead of `pari_tgz'.  However, in this case
   the files WON'T be auto-patched.

   As a last-resort solution, there is also a possibility to use an already
   compiled PARI library.  See the documentation in README and INSTALL files.]

Could not find GP/PARI build directory, please run Makefile.PL
with paridir=/directory option.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Math-Pari-2.010808. See C:\Users\script\.cpanm\work\1438929213.2276\build.log for details.
```

Comment: The first line of your log says `cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7039 on perl 5.018004 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread` ... Notice MSWin32-***x64***-multi-thread.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd add a note for anyone coming here as a result of a Google search after their own Math::Pari install fails under Strawberry Perl.
Here is what worked for me (Strawberry 5.22):

A. from the cpan shell, tried to `install Math::Pari`. this failed

B. Downloaded pari-2.1.7 and placed the extracted folder `pari-2.1.7` in the cpan build folder that was created in (0). This is found, by default, in C:\Strawberry\cpan\build

C.`perl Makefile.PL Configure machine=none`

D. `dmake`

E. `dmake install`

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that 64 bit versions of perl are not supported. It also means that if you're sure that you're running a 32 bit version incorrectly detected as 64 bit, you can try opening a command line and then doing

```
cd C:\Users\script\.cpanm\work\1438929213.2276\
perl Makefile.PL force_download
```