# What to do for Math::Pari in cpan terminal

Tags: perl, module, pari

I found this one relevant question on problems with installing Math::Pari, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871681/error-while-installing-mathpari). Except this is for shell and I have cpanm. I downloaded the latest version of Pari, Pari 2-7-6. Where should I extract the files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pari-2-7-6 to install Math::Pari in perl (not in cpan shell however) successfully? Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm Math::Pari
--> Working on Math::Pari
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IL/ILYAZ/modules/Math-Pari-2.01080900.zip ... OK
Configuring Math-Pari-2.01080900 ... N/A
! Configure failed for Math-Pari-2.01080900. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476648581.10216\build.log for details.
```

Comment: did you open `c:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476648581.10216\build.log` to look at the error(s) like the very last line of the output stated? Edit your question with that info.

Comment: @stevieb the --force does not work, it is a matter of where to extract the Pari 2-7-6 files I am concerned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way on Windows:

1. Download and extract the module: https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Pari
2. `cd` into the directory you created when extracting
3. `perl Makefile.PL force_download` <- this downloads things to the right place
4. `dmake`
5. `dmake install`